# Matlab: Fastest method to split a string at the last period character

Tags: string, performance, matlab

I have to write a program in Matlab, the performance is quite important since it handles a lot of files.

I have to find the last file extension of a filename and split it there.

e.g. `file.name.tar.gz` should be split into `file.name.tar` and `gz`

I identified 3 methods to do this but I don't know which is the fastest.

1.

```
javaFilename = java.lang.String(fileName);
lastDot = javaFilename.lastIndexOf('.');
name = char(javaFilename.substring(0, lastDot-1));    
ext = char(javaFilename.substring(lastDot+1));
```

2.

```
dots = findstr(fileName, '.');
lastDot = dots(length(dots));
name = fileName(1:lastDot-1);
ext = fileName(lastDot+1:end);
```

3.

```
[name tempExt] = strtok(fileName, '.');
while tempExt
    [temp2 tempExt] = strtok(fileName, '.');
    if tempExt
       name = strcat(name, '.', temp2);
    end
end
ext = temp2(2:end);
```

I think the third one is the worst. But how about the other methods?
Can you come up with anything that is faster than the methods described by me?

Comment: instead of 
`lastDot = dots(length(dots));` you can use `lastDot = dots(end);`

Comment: You have hundreds of filenames to process, so even the slowest of these solutions will take what? A millisecond more to process than the fastest method? This seems like a foolish optimization to me.

Comment: As you can see in Richantes answer, the slowest method takes about 2300 times as much time as the fastest, and thus it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test these by doing something like:

```
tic;
fileName = 'testFileName.ext';
for i=1:100000
  <find last dot>
end
toc;
```

I benchmarked yours and found the second one was much faster.

My solution would be

```
for index=length(fileName):-1:1
  if (fileName(index) == '.')
    break;
  end
end
```

The times I got were:

Java Solution: 23 seconds

findstr Solution: 0.4 seconds

strtok Solution: (didn't terminate; maybe I copied it wrong)

reverse for-loop Solution: 0.01 seconds

The advantage of my solution over findstr and strtok is that:
a) it only looks for one dot, rather than all of them
b) it starts from the end of the string (presumably most file extensions will be 2-4 letters long).

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarking technique, didn't know about tic and toc. Also your solution is the fastest. In the strtok solution I had an error. In line 3 it should be `[temp2 tempExt] = strtok(tempExt, '.');`.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in command `fileparts` does what you need, but with probably rather a lot of overhead/error checking etc that might not be necessary. If you look at lines around 100, it does

```
ind = find(name == '.', 1, 'last');

ext = name(ind:end);
name(ind:end) = [];
```

where `name` is the input filename. This is pretty similar to your second suggestion - it may be a little faster or slower, I haven't done the timing.